# Can't fetch data from strapi

Tags: node.js, fetch-api, strapi

I have problem with fetching data to my website .pl from strapi, which is set on vps uand has url http:///admin. I use ubuntu ngnix.

I know I can't fetch data from insecure connection http to secure with https, but how to fix that? Should I run strapi on https and if yes, how to achieve that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.